# Apple Developer Programに法人で登録する必要性

Tags: apple, app-store

#### 質問したいこと

Apple Developer Programには個人と法人の違いはなんでしょうか。
また、個人ではなく法人で作るメリットはどのようなものが考えられますか。

#### 前提

会社としてアプリを作成し、App Storeに配信しようと考えています。
そこで配信するためにApple Developer Programに登録しようと思うのですが法人と個人どちらで登録すればいいのか迷っています。
法人で登録した場合チームで活動できるのはメリットだと思うのですが、個人で登録し一つのApple IDを複数人で使い回せば同様のことができるのではないかとも考えてしまいます。
また、会社で管理するアプリという性質上法人で登録した方がアプリの管理や引き継ぎ、著作権等管理が容易にできると思うのですがどうなのでしょうか。
なんとなく企業から出すのだから法人にした方がいいのかとも思いますが、確信が持てていません。お力添えのほどよろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 個人か法人かに関わらず、「一つの ID 
 を複数人で共有」という考え方がそもそも NG な気がします。

Comment: 元々の疑問はともかく、手続きとか個人から法人へ切り替えた例とかのこれらの記事が何か参考になるかもしれません。[App storeでアプリを公開するために法人でApple IDを取得する](https://blog.regrex.jp/tag/apple-developer-program/), [【2022年10月】 最新版 Apple Developer Program【法人】登録手順](https://shusanblog.net/2019/10/04/post-8/), [【2021年版+画像15枚】法人でApple Developer Programに登録する手順](https://pentagon.tokyo/app/1305/), [Apple Developer Programに法人登録する際に気になった点](https://qiita.com/y_taka/items/1ee38725e50ae26a435e), [Apple Developer Programを個人から法人に切り替える方法に関するメモ](https://develop.hateblo.jp/entry/apple-dev-corporation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Appleによる説明](https://developer.apple.com/jp/support/app-account/)によると、「個人、個人事業主／個人経営者の場合」は個人として、「企業、非営利団体、ジョイントベンチャー、パートナーシップ、政府機関の従業員である場合」は組織（法人）としての登録を指定しているようです。なので、

> 会社としてアプリを作成し、App Storeに配信

する場合は、

#### メリット・デメリットについて

Appleの従業員ではないため正確なメリット・デメリットを列挙することは不可能ですが、考えられるデメリットとしては、今後自分で個人用にApple Developer Programに登録できなくなるというのは想像できます。

というのも、個人・組織共通で登録に必要な項目として

> 運転免許証または政府発行の写真付き本人確認書類による本人確認が求められます。

とあります。
このため、もし法人目的での契約であるにも関わらず個人としてApple Developer Programに登録し、自分の身分証を使用、そしてそのApple IDを社内に共有などした場合、今後自分の身分証でのApple Developer Program登録ができなくなる可能性がありそうです。